Unresolved Reference - databinding (both viewbinding and databinding enabled)
I've in the process of converting my build gradle file to kotlin dsl.. Now that I've completed it, I'm getting a databinding error
Unresolved reference: databinding  I am not doing any databinding, I am however doing view binding, both of which I have enabled.
This was all working perfectly before I migrated so I'm assuming there is something in my migration.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below is my build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application")
    id ("kotlin-android")
    id ("kotlin-parcelize")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id ("com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin")
    id ("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id ("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.google.services.gms)
        classpath(libs.gradle.firebase)
        classpath(libs.dagger.hilt.gradle.plugin)
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "*****"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        packaging {
            resources {
                excludes += "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
                excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE"
                excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE"
                excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
                excludes += "META-INF/ASL2.0"
                excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
            }
        }

        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    
    testOptions {
        unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true

            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }

        debug {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            enableUnitTestCoverage = true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    lint {
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
        abortOnError = false
        ignoreWarnings = true
    }

    sourceSets.getByName("main") {
        resources.srcDirs(
            "src/main/res/layouts/main",
            "src/main/res/layouts/home",
            "src/main/res/layouts/rewards",
            "src/main/res/layouts/registration",
            "src/main/res/layouts/order",
            "src/main/res/layouts/more",
            "src/main/res/layouts/profile",
            "src/main/res/layouts",
            "src/main/res",
            "src/main/res/layouts/main/sandbox",
            "src/main/res/layouts/main/sandbox/debug",
            "src/main/res/layouts/main/sandbox/release"
        )
    }

    flavorDimensions.add("minApi")

    productFlavors {
        create("*****") {
            applicationId = "*********"
            targetSdk = 30
            versionName = "1.0.0"
            dimension = "minApi"
            buildConfigField("String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"*******\"")
            resValue("string", "application_id", "*********")
            resValue("string", "C2D", "****************")
            resValue("string", "app_name", "Sandbox")
            resValue("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ff0d0d0d")
        }

        create("*****") {
            applicationId = "**********"
            targetSdk = 33
            minSdk = 26
            versionCode = 19
            versionName = "3.0.0"
            dimension = "minApi"
            buildConfigField("String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"************\"")
            resValue("string", "application_id", "*************")
            resValue("string", "C2D", "*****************")
            resValue("string", "app_name", "***********")
            resValue("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ff0d0d0d")
        }

        create("*****") {
            applicationId = "**************"
            targetSdk = 33
            minSdk = 24
            dimension = "minApi"
            versionCode = 80
            versionName = "3.0.6"
            buildConfigField("String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"**********\"")
            resValue ("string", "application_id", "**************")
            resValue ("string", "C2D", "***********")
            resValue ("string", "app_name", "******")
            resValue ("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ff0d0d0d")
        }

        create("*******") {
            applicationId = "****************"
            targetSdk = 33
            minSdk = 24
            dimension = "minApi"
            versionCode = 27
            versionName = "1.1.9"
            buildConfigField("String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"************\"")
            resValue ("string", "application_id", "*************")
            resValue ("string", "C2D", "**************")
            resValue ( "string", "app_name", "***")
            resValue ("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ffffff")
        }

        create("*****") {
            applicationId = "*************"
            targetSdk = 33
            minSdk = 24
            dimension = "minApi"
            versionCode = 13
            versionName = "1.1.0"
            buildConfigField("String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"*******\"")
            resValue ("string", "application_id", "*********")
            resValue ("string", "C2D", "*********")
            resValue ( "string", "app_name", "Order")
            resValue ("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ffffff")
        }

        create("********") {
            applicationId = "com.touchnet.orderahead"
            targetSdk = 33
            minSdk = 24
            dimension = "minApi"
            versionCode = 24
            versionName = "1.1.7"
            buildConfigField("String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"********\"")
            resValue ("string", "application_id", "********")
            resValue ("string", "C2D", "********")
            resValue ( "string", "app_name", "********")
            resValue ("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ffffff")
        }

        create("********") {
            applicationId = "********"
            targetSdk = 33
            minSdk = 24
            dimension = "minApi"
            versionCode = 2
            versionName = "1.0.0"
            buildConfigField("String", "PRODUCT_NAME", "\"********\"")
            resValue ("string", "application_id", "********")
            resValue ("string", "C2D", "********")
            resValue ( "string", "app_name", "********")
            resValue ("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ffffff")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))

        //Dependency Injection
        implementation(libs.hilt.android)
        kapt(libs.hilt.android)
        kapt(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
        annotationProcessor(libs.hilt.compiler)

        //View
        implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
        implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
        implementation(libs.customtoast)
        implementation(libs.picasso.transformations)
        implementation(libs.picasso)
        implementation(libs.qrgen)
        implementation(libs.accessibility.tools)
        implementation(libs.apachecommons.text)
        implementation(libs.custom.progressindicator)
        implementation(libs.decocharting)
        implementation(libs.avilibrary)

        //Coroutines
        implementation(libs.coroutines.android)
        implementation(libs.coroutines.core)

        //LiveData
        implementation(libs.livedata.ktx)
        kapt(libs.livedata.lifecycle.compiler)
        implementation(libs.livedata.lifecycle.extensions)

        // ViewModel
        implementation(libs.viewmodel.ktx)
        implementation(libs.viewmodel.compose)
        implementation(libs.viewmodel.savedstate)
        implementation(libs.viewmodel.lifecycleruntime.ktx)

        //Networking
        implementation(libs.retrofit)
        implementation(libs.retrofit.gson.converter)
        implementation(libs.okhttp.logging.interceptor)
        implementation(project(":devenvironmentswitcher"))
        implementation(libs.okhttp)
        implementation(libs.gson)
        implementation(libs.gson.extras)
        implementation(libs.loopj.async)

        implementation(libs.material)

        //Database
        implementation(libs.room.runtime)
        implementation(libs.room.ktx)
        kapt(libs.room.compiler.kapt)

        //Analytics
        implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
        implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics)
        implementation(libs.firebase.analytics)
        implementation(libs.firebase.performance)

        //Androidx
        implementation(libs.androidx.recyclerview)
        implementation(libs.androidx.cardview)
        implementation(libs.androidx.v4legacysupport)
        implementation(libs.androidx.browser)
        implementation(libs.androidx.exif)
        implementation(libs.androidx.multidex)
        implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)

        //Messaging
        implementation(libs.firebase.messaging)
        implementation(libs.firebase.core)
        implementation(libs.azure.notification.handler)
        implementation(libs.azure.notification.hub)

        //Play Services
        implementation(libs.playservices.auth)
        implementation(libs.playservices.gcm)
        implementation(libs.playservices.location)
        implementation(libs.playservices.maps)
        implementation(libs.playservices.vision)
        implementation(libs.playservices.licenses)

        //Encryption
        implementation(libs.spongy.castle)
        implementation(libs.scotty.aes.crypt)

        //Testing
        testImplementation(libs.test.junit)
        testImplementation(libs.test.hilt.testing)
        testImplementation(libs.test.coroutines.test)
        testImplementation(libs.test.mockk)
        kaptTest(libs.test.hilt.compiler.testing)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.test.junit.androidx)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.test.rules)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.test.junit.ktx)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.test.espresso.core)
        implementation(libs.test.arch.testing)

        //Misc
        implementation(libs.scotty.rootbeer)
        implementation(libs.joda)
        implementation(libs.device.names)
        implementation(libs.iocard)
    }
}


Just to give an idea of the errors in class:


Does anyone have any suggestions on what has gone wrong here?  I'd really appreciate it as I am pulling my hair out :D
